# How to recursivelly npm install all dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have many `package.json` files in my application. Each module has its own dependencies written in its own `package.json`. How can I install all dependencies at once?

I tried to run `npm install` and it installed dependencies only according to `package.json` in directory where i ran `npm install`

Comment: `npm install` will take care of this.

Comment: It doesn't or at least it doesn't work. I've updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm `prefix` parameter:

```
npm i --prefix <nested_dir_name>
```

For the following project structure:

```
- client
  - package.json
- server
  - package.json
- package.json
```

You should use the following command to install the dependencies in all folders:

```
npm i && npm i --prefix client && npm i --prefix server
```

Comment: But I'd have to define every folder there. I want it to search recursively for all `package.json`s